# jQuery drag and drop with revert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery UI, I've just set up a simple test with `draggable` and `droppable`

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="Donut" id="a" class="drag"><span id="4" class="drop" >Eclair</span>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="Eclair" id="b" class="drag"><span id="3" class="drop">Donut</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to drag the first image and drop into the related span.Along with this if i drag and drop first image at `id="4"`  it should revert back to its original position.Similarly when i drag and drop second image at `id="3"`  it should revert back to its original position.

script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#a").draggable({
        revert: "valid",
    });
    $("#b").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
    });
    $(".drop").droppable({
         accept: '.drop',
    });
});
```

I can drag the image but could not drop it in a correct position.What i am doing wrong?

css:

```
.drag,.drop{
    width:130px !important;
    height: 130px !important;
    border:2px solid !important;
    margin-top:10px !important;
    margin-left: 15% !important;
}
.drop{
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: 30% !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jjewhwLt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bit of trouble understanding the question here, but i'll give it my best shot at explaining what I think you're trying to achieve.

I'd recommend in the future to start naming out what you're trying to do clearly so that you yourself can understand it while you're working. Stuff like "A" and "B", "3" and "4" etc. will get confusing very very fast with what you're working on.

What I took from this was that you are trying to get each container to accept it's corresponding image. Here's a cleaned up version of your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hr3vf3L/

I've separated out the images + drop areas in the HTML first and replaced the images that were broken with placeholders:

```
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120?text=donut" alt="Donut" id="donut" class="drag">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120?text=eclair" alt="Eclair" id="eclair" class="drag">
</div>

<div class="drop-areas">
  <div class="drop-area" id="eclairArea">Eclair</div>
  <div class="drop-area" id="donutArea">Donut</div>
</div>
```

Then cleaned up the CSS a little to make it a bit more generic:

```
.drop-areas {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.drop-area,
.drag {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.drag { border: none; }
```

Then finally your JS, which I hope makes more sense for you now. `revert` within a `draggable` function when named `invalid` will send the square back to where it was if it isn't in an area where it's accepted, which is explained by the `droppable` functions, which in this case I've separated out to make a little more sense to you, but you could I assume, make this programmatically check which image is being dropped in. As you can see, `#eclairArea` is set up to only accept the `#eclair` and vice-versa.

```
$(function () {
  $(".drag").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
  });

  $("#eclairArea").droppable({
    accept: '#eclair'
  });

  $("#donutArea").droppable({
    accept: '#donut'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to style the elements a bit different, add the `draggable()` to the `.drag` class and you can then append the `droppable()` to the `.drag` elements. I've also added `data-id` to both drag and drop elements to be able to match them. I hope this is what you're looking for:

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jjewhwLt/1/)**.

```
$(".drag").draggable({
  revert: 'invalid'
});
$(".drop").droppable({
  accept: function(drag) {
    var drop_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var drag_id = $(drag).attr('data-id');
    return drop_id === drag_id;
  }
});
```

Comment: @krish This is the better solution as it works with classes and not specifically targeted elements